# How to dynamically configure Nav2 bt_navigator xml?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to dynamically **change/re-configure** the **xml**(param) of Nav2 bt_navigator **without relaunching** whole Nav2 bringup with different praram file.

Is there any way to change the bt_navigator params from *other ros2 node*?

For example: Changing  the behaviour from *navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery* to *navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery*

Thanks you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403295/how-to-dynamically-configure-nav2-bt_navigator-xml-?/) by [jainr](https://answers.ros.org/users/92132/jainr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2022-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In every single navigation request, you can specify which behavior tree you'd like to use, so you can easily change behavior every single navigation request if you like. If you'd like to change mid-action, you can always preempt the currently running navigation request with a new one using a different behavior tree (but I assume you mean changing behaviors between navigation requests, not in the middle of a current executing one).

By the way, we support Nav Through Poses & Nav To Pose as 2 separate actions that can be called by default with Nav2, you don't need to relaunch anything. You can just call the action you like (but that's specific to the 2 "styles" of navigation for Nav to Pose and Nav Through Poses). You can't call them both at the same time since they're mutually exclusive, but you can call them sequentially with or without specifying specific BT files for use to your heart's desire.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [n000oob](https://answers.ros.org/users/130069/n000oob/) on 2023-03-14**:
is this applicable if say I want an automatic transition from slam mode to navigation only mode? (from slam:=True to slam:=False)

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2023-03-15**:
That is not related to the behavior tree.